# How is the previous transaction hash calculated?

Tags: transactions, client, spending

Can anyone provide a clear example on how to calculate a previous transaction hash?

Say I want to create a new transaction, I get that the hash is calculated by doubling `sha256` a message **m**, but I'm having a hard time understanding the structure of **m**.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to calculate previous transaction hash, because it is already known. 
To spend the previous output you just have to know

- tx hash
- output index in this tx
- output value
- output script

plus you should choose

- fee
- new address

then create some byte data and sign it with appropriate private key

Good manual you can find here: [How to redeem a basic Tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx)

Answer (score 0):

You hash the header.  Format is here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm
The body contains the transactions.
Here's the Bitcoin transaction format:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions