# how generate <sig> part of scriptSig in bitcoin transactions

Tags: raw-transaction, input-script

I studied many links about bitcoin trxs and about generating scriptSig.
Finally I couldn't understand how to make this part.

for example I read this links:

[What is relation between scriptSig and scriptPubKey?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8250/what-is-relation-between-scriptsig-and-scriptpubkey)

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions

[How do you create a scriptsig for a new raw tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58076/how-do-you-create-a-scriptsig-for-a-new-raw-tx/58089)

[How to redeem a basic Tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx)

[How to create the <sig> <PubK> part in "scriptSig"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36665/how-to-create-the-sig-pubk-part-in-scriptsig)

http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

I found that I must sign a thing but whats that thing ?

exactly and step by step What should I put together and then sign it?

specially if I had more than 1 input how make sigscript ?

I have a library that does the sign operation for me. however, I don't know what structure I need to use for the message that is going to be signed especially when there are multiple outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The data to be signed is called *Hash Preimage*. Then you sign the double SHA256 of hash preimage, which is 256-bits long. Before hashing, the data must be formed as shown in [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5241/38618). If you're signing a SegWit transaction, the contents of the preimage changes, as defined in [BIP 143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki).

Then you can use the formulae [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5767), Eq. 2:

```
(x1, y1) = k × G(x, y) mod p
r = x1 mod n
```

`k` is a random number, `G` is the generator, `p` is the prime modulo, etc.

Then,

```
s = (k^-1 (h(m) + d * r)) mod n
```

`d` is the private key, `h(m)` is the double SHA256 result. Now, you can use `r`, `s` to create the DER-encoded signature.

Comment: I read [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx/5241#5241) but this solution was for only a transaction with one output. if my outputs becomes 2 or 3 now how must make scriptsig?

Comment: Here's [an example](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG#Code_samples_and_raw_dumps) with multiple outputs. Here's the specification for outputs in [BIP143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#specification), scroll down to `hashOutputs`.

Comment: I read [this link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG#Code_samples_and_raw_dumps) But it's not explained at all about how the script signature section was created !!

Comment: After you formed the data in the examples, you double sha256 it and use the equations above. Do you want to learn how to do that using libsecp256k1?

Comment: no. I have a library that do the sign operation for me. I only want to know exactly which parts of the transaction do I need to put together, and what order should I use before sign operation with more than one input and one output ?