# Do i need to sign each input in a raw transaction?

Tags: transaction-input, signrawtransaction

I've been reading up about raw transactions on [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-raw-transaction) and there are two examples [Simple](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-raw-transaction) and [Complex](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#complex-raw-transaction).

What I can't tell from the information provided is if it necessary to sign each of the inputs separately, or whether you can just sign the entire tx with one.

So two examples:

1. Input 1 came from address A and input 2 came from address A.
2. Input 1 came from address B and input 2 came from address C.

For example 1, my assumption is that I could just use

```
bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction RAW_TX
```

but for example 2 I would have to use

```
 bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction RAW_TX [] ["ADDR_B_PRIVATE_KEY"]
 bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX [] ["$ADDR_B_PRIVATE_KEY"]
```

Comment: next to the answers below, this is at the tx level itself, if not using a wallet: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41209/how-to-sign-a-transaction-with-multiple-inputs?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

> Do i need to sign each input in a raw transaction?

Technically, yes. But software like Bitcoin Core Client signs all inputs where the private keys are known. And of course, leave unsigned/untouched all other inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction RAW_TX
```

if the private keys of all inputs of that transaction are in your Bitcoin Core (or bitcoind).

Comment: And what if the keys are not imported (but known anyway)? How should it be added as a argument? a list with each key, all in the same order as the outputs ?

Comment: @FeedTheWeb Do this for each key: importprivkey PRIVKEY "" false Don't forget to type false, and.the order doesn't matter. If this doesn't work, do a rescan after adding each key (but probably it won't be needed.) If you have lots of keys, I may write you a little piece of code that reads the PrivKeys from a file and imports them.

Comment: And if I don't want to import/rescan (because it takes forever), the syntax should be `bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction RAW_TX [] ["PRIVKEY1", "PRIVKEY2"]` , right?

Comment: @FeedTheWeb No, `importprivkey PRIVKEY "" false` won't rescan, because the last argument is `rescan?`, `false`. And you're right, you don't need to importprivkey, your command is correct.