# ECKey.ECDSASignature creation

Tags: private-key, bitcoinj, ecdsa, java

I have my `ECKey key`. In order to create an `ECDSASignature` object with BitcoinJ, we have to call `ECDSASignature mySignature = key.sign(Sha256Hash input)`.

Is the `Sha256Hash input` my message? Or is it the result of `Sha256(byte[] myArray)`?

What if I don't have a message to sign? Is it acceptable to sign the `key.getPrivKeyBytes()` in order to create an `ECDSASignature`, or it is unacceptable because it reveals information including in `getPrivKeyBytes()` and as a result reveal my private key?

And if it is unacceptable what must be my message? Can I can sign whatever I want in order to create my `ECDSASignature`?

Comment: Are you trying to sign a transaction? There are better ways of doing that in bitcoinj. What are you trying to sign?

Comment: Let's say that first: i am trying to sign a transaction and as a second secnario that i am going to sign a message in the form of String variable.Which are these better ways?Thanks.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx

Comment: Thanks. I will actually create a message (as a String variable) rather than a whole transaction,and finally i will sign this message to fulfill my program's functionality desires.

Comment: @Top If you're trying to sign a transaction, you should use `Wallet.signTransaction(Wallet.SendRequest.forTx(transaction));` If you're trying to sign a message, you should hash the message first with SHA256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing the bytes of the private key of `ECKey key` is unacceptable because you are vulnerable for realeasing information about your private key.

In the case of signing a **message**(as a String) you have to estimate the :

```
 byte[] result= sha256(message)
```

The result will be a byte[] and this array finally will insert to the :

```
 Sha256Hash input= new Sha256Hash(result);
```

Then the procedure is simple in order to produce the **ECDSASignature**.
You have to do the following:

```
ECDSASignature signature= key.sign(input);
```

and finally in order to validate your signature you have to check the following:

```
key.verify(input, signature)
```