# How to get the private key in hex from the output of dumpprivkey

Tags: private-key

I am trying to create raw transactions according to the excellent answer of runeks here:
[How to redeem a basic Tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx/5241#5241)

But there he starts with a private key in hex format
`18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725`

and I have one in base58 given by bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey:

`bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey 154G5oUywHU3pESNy4oBBpkmAGqRZiYxBk
KzRVLwCuCi2tH2PpSNZnwUqPwg6gaqXAM2LWobUurzAsNdC5JesE`

How do I get it in hex in the right format?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I managed to do it with the excellent bitcoin-tool by matja
https://github.com/matja/bitcoin-tool

`git clone https://github.com/matja/bitcoin-tool.git`

`cd bitcoin-tool`

`make test`

`./bitcoin-tool --input-type private-key-wif --input-format base58check --output-type private-key --output-format hex --network bitcoin  --input "KzRVLwCuCi2tH2PpSNZnwUqPwg6gaqXAM2LWobUurzAsNdC5JesE"`

which gave me 
5f92519eef7ec4e37cbcd25f9ba4a82e5acf9a8cd274d4d3aa3aa727fd7b6969

as a result.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key
Private keys associated with compressed public keys are 52 characters and start with a capital L or K on mainnet. Your second line looks pretty much like a privkey (KzRVLwCuCi2tH2PpSNZnwUqPwg6gaqXAM2LWobUurzAsNdC5JesE), just it is 53 chars long... sure your data is not garbled? 
Once you have your privkey you'd need the base58check encoding, like provided on Ken Shirriff's blog: http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html
which again is explained in the wiki: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding