# Is the Bitcoin Transaction ID also the "Hash of things to sign" for the signature generation?

Tags: signature, transaction-id

As a random example, is the transaction id:

114be7fea4d3dd0cf2e88a8fa9a56d4ea741efbabd07d61d08cf0810be2254fd

Also the hash that was used as the "hash of things to sign" for the "signature generation" for this transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The transaction id contains the signatures. But you are making the signatures at the same time, so it can't possibly be the hash that is being signed. [How to redeem a basic Tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx) describes the actual sighashing algorithm.

Comment: Where is the Hash of things to sign on the blockchain/explorer for that transaction then?

Comment: Read the question I linked to in my answer. The hash is not stored anywhere as it can be calculated on-the-fly (like the txid). Since this information is not necessary for most users (basically no one actually needs that information if they are looking up a transaction) it is not given on block explorers.

Comment: Know of an easy way to find out the hash?  Like, "copy this, paste it here, and then click this calculate button"?

Comment: No. The hash is specific to each input (so multiple hashes for transactions with multiple inputs) and requires knowing the blockchain history as it requires data from the transaction that the input is spending from. AFAIK, there is no service which will give you all of the hashes that are signed. However, it is fairly easy to calculate yourself if you read the question I linked to.

Comment: I read what was in that link...it made me want to bash my head against a wall.  It seemed like doing such would be a more productive use of my time than trying to make sense of everything in that post, 8(