# How OP_CHECKSIG knows the source of sig in pay to pubkey hash transaction

Tags: transactions, script, signature

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Standard_Transaction_to_Bitcoin_address_.28pay-to-pubkey-hash.29

The last step of pay to pubkey hash transaction is to check the signature of the previous transaction tx hash  and pubkey .

But how the script interpreter knows the sig is the signature of the previous transition hash, what if the sig is the signature of some other content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how the script interpreter knows the sig the signature of the
>   previous transition hash, what if the sig is the signature of some
>   other content?

It also compares the signed data with the transaction hash itself. In general, this is how digital signatures work. If the data isn't ***signed by the right key***, and ***data hash doesn't match***, then the signature is invalid. See [src/script/interpreter.cpp L#1264](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.16.2/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L1264).

**This verification process ensures two things:**
1. The person has the private key which corresponds with the public key provided.
2. The data has not been tampered with.

Comment: The code in SignatureHash() looks reconstruct (l1217~1235) part of the transaction and hash again. Then use pubKey to verify the hash and sig. 
Is the "data" you mentioned above is that the reconstructed byte list?

Comment: It's actually not simple, but there is a good explanation of what is hashed and signed here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5241/60443

Comment: One more question, in step 9, why the sender will decide the fee (0.001) in the process of generation input. If it is true, how the verifier could know what is the fee from the hash code? Actually, from the code in GitHub, it looks like it uses the original amount directly, and in the gitbub, it output the amount and then sequence (FFFFFFFF), but in that post, the order like amount first, then output script in step 9 and step 10.