# Bitcoin create TX. What is 'hash_type'?

Tags: transactions, protocol, source-code

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5241/92798
What is the meaning of item 13?
Why is this value chosen? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG

99% transactions use SIGHASH_ALL