# manually signing bitcoin transaction

Tags: transactions, signature, regtest

I'm trying to create a BTC transaction with one input and two outputs, one for change and one OP_RETURN to anchor data. And I'm doing all of that on my regtest backend. The raw unsigned transaction is

```
01000000018be9d0e99e74d69d915e105db1328707f713d42a894909b18a78fe68e1d8290c0000000023210340165231215a98e7a32abce9d410ecd09ac505938b25f9451defa051d591ebf8acffffffff0218ee052a010000001976a9143eb52fb0be4be87edc74848b371547f663e26c7e88ac0000000000000000226a408973d6b447bdda5312b1ef1b5509668672296301dd328d4e55317def98f165d200000000
```

I can then use the bitcoin rpc to sign it and it works, so I'm pretty certain that this part is correct. When I however try to sign it manually I get the error

```
500: {"result":null,"error":{"code":-26,"message":"16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Non-canonical DER signature)"},"id":2}
```

I've followed the steps outlined in [How to redeem a basic Tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx) as well as [Signing a raw transaction with Python ECDSA (or OpenSSL)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36440/signing-a-raw-transaction-with-python-ecdsa-or-openssl) as well as attempted to use pybitcointools to sign the input without success.

The address and private key I use are

```
addr: "mmEXEzUGcMmmiLsfxxM8gB8TQSTkuR1drf"
pk:  "cTyF9pebH3kwwzUt5gzaxSDQ1DbqYfx4P1i4d1TyjtSDEeUFgYsk"
```

and stragely, even though the PK is the one given to me by `./bitcoin-cli -regtest dumpprivkey <addr>` does not seem to match the address and I'm not sure why or what it is I need to do to it (it's in WIF format and compressed, i.e. `0x01` appended to the end

The original TX includes the `scriptPubKey` of the utxo. I then double sha256 the whole raw tx (shown above) and replace the scriptPubKey part with the `sigScript | pubkey` using the following code:

```
private_key, compressed_pk = wif_to_private_key(private_key_wif)
tx = bytearray.fromhex(raw_unsigned_transaction) + int(1).to_bytes(4, 'little')

double_sha256_tx = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(tx).digest()).digest()
signing_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(bytearray.fromhex(private_key), curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
public_key = bytearray.fromhex(privtopub(private_key_wif))
signature = signing_key.sign_digest(double_sha256_tx, sigencode=ecdsa.util.sigencode_der) + int(1).to_bytes(1, 'little')
scriptSig = to_varstr(signature) + to_varstr(public_key)
```

to_varstr simply prints [len]|[data] and privtopub is the function from pybitcointools as I couldn't figure out how to go from the compressed private key to the address manually. It's worth noting though that the public_key here that `privtoaddr` from pybitcointools does not return the correct address either which might be the root cause of the issue?

I'd be grateful for any pointers or things to try

cheers
Chris

PS:
another interesting aspect is that the signed transaction I generate is a lot longer than the one generated by the `signtransaction` rpc call:

```
rpc:    01000000018be9d0e99e74d69d915e105db1328707f713d42a894909b18a78fe68e1d8290c0000000023210340165231215a98e7a32abce9d410ecd09ac505938b25f9451defa051d591ebf8acffffffff0218ee052a010000001976a9143eb52fb0be4be87edc74848b371547f663e26c7e88ac0000000000000000226a40ac4f0818b683eeeaa1fbf2f508af2fc22cc814e69025152c70d7c414ebbfc30a00000000
manual: 01000000018be9d0e99e74d69d915e105db1328707f713d42a894909b18a78fe68e1d8290c000000006b483045022100d6e538aa819f3162d5c6a0e4d9ee0323395df89e943c769d96ae939baec5c6920220083a311cb35df3c98d7a6bd0bc80d98a71fbdf8e325ba908ea4b721a4eac8bb301210343395a6e84c7f2b1d50c11f96783664a6f04d66b51befb3befcc57334e2a9abcffffffff0218ee052a010000001976a9143eb52fb0be4be87edc74848b371547f663e26c7e88ac0000000000000000226a40ac4f0818b683eeeaa1fbf2f508af2fc22cc814e69025152c70d7c414ebbfc30a00000000
```

Comment: And what is the exact question? Are you asking for finding all errors (there are much more than one) in your code? Ready to pay?

Comment: Interesting how the communities have degraded to wanting money for everything from actually wanting to help people, but I guess I could be convinced to reward a good answer.

I don't particularly care about the format of the response, either a link to a good resource or an indicator as to what is wrong. happy to read up on things myself

Comment: What is your question in short words?

Comment: I guess 2 questions really:
 - how do I verify that the private key matches the address as it seems to be representing a different one
 - is there something obviously wrong with the signing steps (as it's essentially exactly what I've read in other posts)

Comment: yup, your question took some time to dig into, try to keep it shorter, that will make it easier for others to provide help. @amaclin: looks like deadc0de is new here in the forum, let's be happy to get people willing to dive into bitcoin - let's give him a bit of a hug. He's not asking how to get quickly rich by investing without doing any effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

I verified the keys on https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/bitcoinpaperwallet/generate-wallet.html?design=alt-testnet#, and choose testnet on the first tab, and then the second tab (print front). They match, so good. Then I tried to decompose your line, where you say it is the signtransaction call. This seems to me unsigned:

```
 TX_IN[0] Script Sig (uchar[])
  210340165231215A98E7A32ABCE9D410ECD09AC505938B25F9451DEFA051D591EBF8AC 
  ##################################################################
  ### tcls_in_sig_script.sh: decode SIG_script OPCODES from a TX ###
  ##################################################################
    21: OP_DATA_0x21:     type tag indicating LENGTH
    03: OP_INT_0x03
        40165231215A98E7:A32ABCE9D410ECD0
        9AC505938B25F945:1DEFA051D591EBF8
        AC
    * This terminates the Public Key (X9.63 COMPRESSED form)
    * corresponding bitcoin address is:
   mvVWbgb3sZeEz495eDoaem79Qi876zuG9S
```

whereas the second line (manual) looks good:

```
 TX_IN[0] Script Sig (uchar[])
  483045022100D6E538AA819F3162D5C6A0E4D9EE0323395DF89E943C769D96AE939BAEC5C6920220083A311CB35DF3C98D7A6BD0BC80D98A71FBDF8E325BA908EA4B721A4EAC8BB301210343395A6E84C7F2B1D50C11F96783664A6F04D66B51BEFB3BEFCC57334E2A9ABC 
  ##################################################################
  ### tcls_in_sig_script.sh: decode SIG_script OPCODES from a TX ###
  ##################################################################
    48: OP_DATA_0x48:     push hex 48 (decimal 72) bytes as data
    30: OP_SEQUENCE_0x30: type tag indicating SEQUENCE, begin sigscript
    45: OP_LENGTH_0x45:   length of R + S
    02: OP_INT_0x02:      type tag indicating INTEGER
    21: OP_LENGTH_0x21:   this is SIG R
        00D6E538AA819F31:62D5C6A0E4D9EE03
        23395DF89E943C76:9D96AE939BAEC5C6
        92
    02: OP_INT_0x02:      type tag indicating INTEGER
    20: OP_LENGTH_0x20:   this is SIG S
        083A311CB35DF3C9:8D7A6BD0BC80D98A
        71FBDF8E325BA908:EA4B721A4EAC8BB3
    01: OP_SIGHASHALL:    this terminates the ECDSA signature (ASN1-DER structure)
    #########################################################
    ### procedure to strictly check DER-encoded signature ###
    #########################################################
    Minimum and maximum size constraints                        - ok
    scriptsig always starts with 0x30                           - ok
    length 138 chars is less than actual sig length (144 chars) - ok
           (hex 0x45, decimal 69, 138 chars)
    length of R coordinate (66) >= 0                            - ok
    length of S coordinate (64) >= 0                            - ok
    S-Value is within scriptsig boundaries                      - ok
    Make sure the R & S length covers the entire signature      - ok
    S-value must be smaller than N/2                            - ok
    strictly check DER-encoded signature                        - ok
    #########################################################
    21: OP_DATA_0x21:     type tag indicating LENGTH
    03: OP_INT_0x03
        43395A6E84C7F2B1:D50C11F96783664A
        6F04D66B51BEFB3B:EFCC57334E2A9ABC

    * This terminates the Public Key (X9.63 COMPRESSED form)
    * corresponding bitcoin address is:
   mmEXEzUGcMmmiLsfxxM8gB8TQSTkuR1drf
```

so also all DER checking of the siggnature is ok. However I see the address being different, effectivly it is the output address, isn't it? 
Maybe you mixed up some addresses while signing manually?
What is the address you are spending from?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response, had some personal thing come up and no time to continue with this until now.

The idea, or intention is to transfer money from `mmEXEzUGcMmmiLsfxxM8gB8TQSTkuR1drf` to `mmEXEzUGcMmmiLsfxxM8gB8TQSTkuR1drf`, i.e. transferring the coins to myself, while including some transaction fees as well as an OP_RETURN output for data anchoring. I'm not sure what address you're referring to though?

Comment: in the first tx I see address "mvVWbgb3sZeEz495eDoaem79Qi876zuG9S", in the second "mmEXEzUGcMmmiLsfxxM8gB8TQSTkuR1drf". If the first one is ok, then you have used the correct priv key to the address. Did you use same privkey for second address?