# Bitcoin raw transaction hash signing

Tags: raw-transaction, raw-data

I was just wondering when you're at the double hashing part of making a transaction do you need to specify the scriptpubsig like:

```
01000000
01
1c615595ac93432de87bcc519f2ddffce1a5f88bd4ec3e586c56e05b35e13767
01000000
00
ffffffff
02
6400000000000000
19
76a9143b65057d8846147349a816f41a6c5cc1e706a02b88ac
a086010000000000
19
76a914f323ec06f263e6ba625de2cf27f1495294065b8088ac
00000000
01000000
```

or does it need to be like:

```
01000000 
01
eccf7e3034189b851985d871f91384b8ee357cd47c3024736e5676eb2debb3f2 
01000000  
19 
76a914010966776006953d5567439e5e39f86a0d273bee88ac  
ffffffff 
01 
605af40500000000 
19     
76a914097072524438d003d23a2f23edb65aae1bb3e46988ac 
00000000  
01000000
```

main differences:

example 1:

```
 1c615595ac93432de87bcc519f2ddffce1a5f88bd4ec3e586c56e05b35e13767 //tx of input
 01000000
 00 //script len
 //no script
 ffffffff //requence
```

example 2

```
eccf7e3034189b851985d871f91384b8ee357cd47c3024736e5676eb2debb3f2  //tx of input
01000000  
19 //script len
76a914010966776006953d5567439e5e39f86a0d273bee88ac   //script
ffffffff //sequence
```

Comment: You want the scriptsig there. You can find out all you need and more here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32628/redeeming-a-raw-transaction-step-by-step-example-required

Comment: the thing that got me was the  result of step 14.. i presumed that it would be equal to createrawtransaction output.... thanks