# How to use Signed Hash to Send Coins in bitcoinj

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, java

I am very new to bitcoinj library. I am using 0.14.7 version of bitcoinj and developing my own application in java. I have created a watch-only wallet by using the tPub of the Offline wallet. Upto Receiving payments on watch-only wallet, it is working fine. Now, i have to spend those coins. For that, I have created a transaction and found its transaction Hash.

To sign that transaction Hash with private key, I have followed [How to sign raw transaction given a private key and SHA hash (in java)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50562/how-to-sign-raw-transaction-given-a-private-key-and-sha-hash-in-java) code. and now I am getting the signed hash. Please guide me that how can I use this signed hash to send and broadcast the transaction.?

Your help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

The sample code is given below:

```
// Through this way, I am finding the Transaction Hash.

SendRequest request = SendRequest.to(Address.fromBase58(params,externalAddress), Coin.parseCoin(amount));
request.signInputs = false;
request.tx.getInputs();
request.missingSigsMode = Wallet.MissingSigsMode.USE_DUMMY_SIG;
String hash = request.tx.getHashAsString();

//now using createSignHash method, which is taking transaction hash and signing that with private key and returning the Signed Hex.
System.out.println("Signed Hash : " + createSignHash(hash));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sendrawtransaction signedHex
```

is the rpc you need to call which will submit your raw transaction to local node and network.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying. According to [link] (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions), "raw transaction API was introduced with Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind version 0.7". I am using bitcoinj. How to use sendRawTransaction here? Can you help me to know the process for bitcoinj? or is there any alternative for sendRatTransaction there?