# signing multiple input raw transaction - algorithm and sighash types

Tags: signature, raw-transaction, input-script, sighash

I have an unsigned raw transaction:

```
01000000020dcc23ccdb3665779a7657577cd33c5c0660e969ea2ffaf5438c58306ebc9dd20100000000ffffffff49508924c21b25ee2ff6aed61ccc202793aa992d3e033f12f2bf4a94d6346d010000000000ffffffff0240420f00000000001976a9140d7ca1e17524d6c96209cf503fb053613cecf8f688aca0f703000000000017a91452636ce984783dac880e139fa3b69b4d9be39ab68700000000
```

I have read these threads:
[How to redeem a basic Tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx)
[Redeeming a raw transaction step by step example required](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32628/redeeming-a-raw-transaction-step-by-step-example-required)

These threads explain signing a raw transaction with 1 input.

**Questions**

Do I understand correctly that both inputs are to be signed separately?
So first, we sign the first one, then the second one. To sign an input we replace *scriptSig* for this input with the *scriptPubKey*, that locks this input. *ScriptSig* for the other one remains blank.

It this correct?

But in both threads in step 13 something is appended at the end of transaction. It is called **hash code type**

What is this? Is this has anything to do with **sighash type byte** the one that is appended to the signature? If not how to determine this value?

What is the correct sighash type for the scenario I described above (signing inputs separately)?
Is this: 0x81 (SIGHASH_ALL | SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY)?
Or should this be 0x01 (SIGHASH_ALL)?

I don't know which one is correct as transaction to be signed contains the other input (without scriptSig set but still, it contains it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that both inputs are to be signed
> separately?

yes

> So first, we sign the first one, then the second one. To sign an input
> we replace scriptSig for this input with the scriptPubKey, that locks
> this input. ScriptSig for the other one remains blank. It this
> correct?

yes

> But in both threads in step 13 something is appended at the end of
> transaction. It is called hash code type. What is this? Is this has
> anything to do with sighash type byte the one that is appended to the
> signature?

yes

> What is the correct sighash type for the scenario I described above
> (signing inputs separately)? Is this: 0x81 (SIGHASH_ALL |
> SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY)? Or should this be 0x01 (SIGHASH_ALL)?

Use 0x01 (SIGHASH_ALL)