# Ho do I generate the output script of a bitcoin transaction?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, raw-data, p2pkh

When I mean output script I mean the output script from step 11 from this question:

[Redeeming a raw transaction step by step example required](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32628/redeeming-a-raw-transaction-step-by-step-example-required)

> Then the actual output script: 76 a9 14 a2fd2e039a86dbcf0e1a664729e09e8007f89510 88 ac ( this is transferring funds back to address 1FromKBPAS8MWsk1Yv1Yiu8rJbjfVioBHc )

In this example the responder used Pkscript from the input of the previous trasaction. However there is no explanation how the hex "a2fd2e039a86dbcf0e1a664729e09e8007f89510" is generated itself. I'm asking because, I don't know what I would insert if I want to use another address as output. As I understand (maybe not) this hex is somehow generated from the bitcoin address "1FromKBPAS8MWsk1Yv1Yiu8rJbjfVioBHc". Is this correct? And how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a P2PKH (Pay-to-public-key-hash) address which means `a2fd2e039a86dbcf0e1a664729e09e8007f89510` is the hash of your public key. [Here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) is a step by step guide on how to go from public key to address

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But as I understand there is no way, how I get a P2PKH out of a bitcoin address. Because the bitcoin address (not the public key) is the only information I get from the receiver, I still can not see how I would get the P2PKH.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I just have to base58 decode the btc adress which results in "00a2fd2e039a86dbcf0e1a664729e09e8007f89510c5214deb", don't know what the numbers before and after stand for but I can work with that.

Comment: I hope that this value is even the right value because at the second answer of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32628/redeeming-a-raw-transaction-step-by-step-example-required someone claimed that specifically this value ("a2fd2e0....") was not correct.

Comment: if you add the base58 decode info to your answer or clarify the solution , I will accept it.

Comment: So, I know have fully understand why there was another value than the "a2fd2e0....". The second responder just used another target address for the transaction. So base58 decoding is the solution.